# SharePoint Database Alternatives

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Right now I am using MS Access to load records, archive records, and delete records from a SharePoint list (2013).

So basically using MS Access as a mini database. I then run a SAS program to move the data from MS Access to a SQL Platform.

One dilemma, my company is not a big fan of MS Access. So, My question is...

Can anyone suggest some alternatives for MS Access but performs in the same manner. The ability to run a query to load, archive, delete records into/out of SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no official alternative for Microsoft Access desktop app.

Consider using unofficial free software LibreOffice and Apache OpenOffice.

More information:

https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/tools/microsoft-access-alternatives-at-a-glance/